# Crystal Report 10.5, set selection formula

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, selection, formula

I am using Crystal Report 10.5.3700.0. I have created a report which is using stored procedure. Now from vb.net code (in VS2005) I set the selection formula like:

```
proSaleByPerson;1.PersonsId=1
```

But when the report load its giving following error "Query Engine Error 'ADO Error Code:0x'", Failed to open a rowset.

Keep in mind that all other reports are working fine only that reports create problem which are using stored procedure, when setting the selection formula.

Comment: Could you post more of your code?

Comment: Do you get any results when you run the stored procedure from SSMS using the same parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the line `"SET NOCOUNT ON"` as the first line of your stored procedure.